# Laravel retrieve data with condition from many-to-many condition

Tags: php, laravel

I have three tables:

```
email_accounts (list of business emails)
-------------
id
email
sender_name
```

```
users
------
id
name
email
```

```
email_accounts_users
--------------------
email_account_id
user_id
```

And the eloquent relationship is declared as:

```
    User
    ------
    public function emailAccounts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(EmailAccount::class,'email_accounts_users');
    }

    EmailAccount
    ------------
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'email_accounts_users');
    }
```

I am trying to fetch rows from `email_accounts` that belongs to current user.
This could be correctly fetched as:

```
$email_acc = \DB::table('email_accounts')
            ->join('email_accounts_users', 'email_accounts_users.email_account_id', 'email_accounts.id')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', 'email_accounts_users.user_id')
            ->select('email_accounts.*')
            ->where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)
            ->get();
dd($email_acc);
```

However, I am trying to get with laravel eloquent model.
So, I tried as follows:

```
$email_acc = EmailAccount::with(['users' => function(){
    $query->where('users_id',auth()->user()->id)
}])->get();
dd($email_acc);
```

However, its returning all the emails from `email_accounts`, rather its filtering the data from users table and sending only the `currently logged in user`. from users table.

However, my requirement is to fetch emails form `email_accounts` that belong to currently logged in users.

Like

Comment: $email_acc = auth()->user()->emailAccounts;

Comment: `users_id` vs. `user_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
$email_acc = EmailAccount::whereHas('users', function($query) {
    $query->where('id',auth()->user()->id);
})
->get();
dd($email_acc);
```

It will return empty collection if the record doesn't exixts

or you can also fetch using logged in user instance

```
$user = auth()->user();
return $user->emailAccounts;
```

**Make sure you defined a perfect relationship**

Read [Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Comment: I don't know how, howver this works:
EmailAccount::whereHas('users', function($query) {
                    $query->where('user_id',auth()->user()->id);
                })->get();
instead of id its `user_id` name form pivot column works

Comment: WhereHas filtering from users table (Relationship). in sort
You can filter with relationship

Answer (score 0):

Specify foreign keys as follows

```
public function emailAccounts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(EmailAccount::class,'email_accounts_users', 'id', 'email_account_id' );
    }

    EmailAccount
    ------------
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'email_accounts_users', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
```